# Raspberry Pi multiple screens

Tags: display

I want to create a setup using a Raspberry Pi 3 where there will be 3 monitors which will have the same output.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may find what you're looking for trying to google for "HDMI splitter" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it in software, the Pi has only one HDMI port.

There are devices called HDMI splitters. They take HDMI in and output multiple copies of the same signal, over multiple HDMIs.

Just plug it in, and all the cables. No need to configure the PI. It will work with and device that outputs HDMI.